# Redirect for login to different origin without disrupting the current page

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm having a challenging design issue that's bumping into the security limitations of browsers.

I'm working on a site that presently uses Username and Password. The front end, every few seconds, makes a JavaScript based "session maintenance" call to the server to validate their session is still valid. If not, the front end one covers their work with an opaque div with a username/password popup for them to revalidate their credentials. Submission is done with JavaScript, and a JSON response. When correct, the opaque div disappears and their work is still sitting there with any pending changes they've made.
(The opaque div is not meant to be a security measure)

I'm rewriting this to work with a certificate instead, but the validation is done with a site having a different origin. When a user requests a page, the host checks if they have provided a valid certificate. If not, the host redirects them to a different page to validate credentials. Once done the host redirects them back to my page, and staples their certificate information for me into the HTTP Request header.

I'd like to implement this new method similarly. Specifically, they're on my page doing work, the session timer expires so an opaque window covers their work with a popup telling them they need to revalidate.  Then the opaque div disappears and their work is still sitting there.

How to detect the need to revalidate, and how to get a signal to the original window showing the validation is complete is the problem.

When my session maintenance call is sent to the server, I think instead of getting a JSON message back with a true/false, I will now get a true when they have a good session, or an HTML response from the redirected host page if they are no longer logged in. I'm pretty sure I can use this to pop up the opaque div.

**New Tab:**

From there I first thought, I'll just have a "login" button on the opaque div that the user can click. It would open a new tab pointing to my validate.php page, which would get redirected to the host page. They'd revalidate and once done, send the user back to my validate.php The original tab could monitor the new table for validate.php to popup, confirming the user logged in.

```
  revalidate() {
     this.newTab = window.open("validate.php", "_blank");
  }
  checkValidated() {
     console.log(rootUrl);
     if (this.newTab.location.href == rootUrl + "validate.php") {
        alert("You are logged in");
        //remove opaque div and whatever else here
     }
  }
```

The host page isn't on the same-origin so I can't see it's url from my original tab, but I hoped once it finally redirected back to my validate.php, on the same-origin, that I'd be able to see it. Not the case, as soon as the tab leaves the origin the access is shut down and never given back.

**Monitor for session creation:**

This idea would leverage the existing session maintenance check that the front end already does. So when the session maintenance makes its call to the server and discovers the session has ended, it does the opaque DIV with the "login" button. Then it immediately starts calling the session maintenance thing every second or two testing for the session to be valid again. The user hits login, they get redirected to validate.php, but the host redirects and has them login, and eventually they get to validate.php which just displays "close this tab and return to your previous tab".

The original tab is still making it's session maintenance calls and naturally gets a confirmation that the user has finished logging in, so then it drops the opaque div.

I think this would work, and it leverages the existing session maintenance call so it would be a quick fix, but it seems like a sloppy user experience.

**Monitor Cookies:**

Another thought was to send a "completed" message to the original tab through a cookie. I've not really messed with cookies much so I'm not sure about this. So, the mainpage.php in the main tab, would open validate.php in a new tab. After revalidating, when the user finally gets to validate.php it sets a "completed" cookie. The mainpage.php would have been monitoring for that cookie so it knows when to drop the opaque div.

This would still require the user to close that second tab. Also if the user revalidated in some other way then the original tab would still be sitting there, unless I made every entry point set the cookie.

**iFrame:**

mainpage.php, instead of popping up the opaque div, it puts an iframe in front of the content and navigates to validate.php. The user gets redirected, logs in, and eventually ends up at my validate.php. That page removes the iframe from the main page by sending some javascript like this:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('revalidation-iframe').hidden = true
```

This seems like a really smooth experience for the user, but I'm not yet sure if the host is going to allow cross origin requests like this.

**User Prompted**

The last thing I've thought of, and what I want to avoid doing is making the user tell me when they've revalidate. So my opaque div would have 2 steps. A login button, and a Continue button. They'd hit the login to get the new tab, and when they're done they go hit continue to drop the opaque div. Yuk.

I'm really scratching my head about the best way to proceed with this. Every idea seems like it would be kind of wonky and maybe error prone. I'm hoping someone has some ideas I haven't thought of, or can point out pitfalls that I need to be aware of.